# Why is (not? (pair? x) [...]) beneficial over ((pair? x) [...])?

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp

Throughout chapter 2 of SICP and particularly [section 2.2.](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%25_sec_2.2) and its corresponding solutions on the Scheme wiki, I am regularly seeing the same pattern when dealing with tree structures:

```
(cond ((null? tree) nil) 
      ((not (pair? tree)) (foo tree)) 
      (else (cons (bar (car tree)) 
                  (bar (cdr tree)))))
```

The second line of these structures are a frequent source of confusion for me. In any other language, I'd expect to see the final two branches swapped as follows:

```
(cond ((null? tree) nil)  
      ((pair? tree) (cons (bar (car tree)) 
                          (bar (cdr tree))))
      (else (foo tree)))
```

So why am I not seeing that in Scheme? Is there some benefit to preferring `(not? (pair? x) [...])` over swapping the branches and removing the `not?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cases usually start with the smallest or most special case and and end with the largest or most general.

With a tree, that would be

1. Empty
2. Leaf
3. All other trees

Comment: I would say this is much like preferring early return in other languages. Get the simple cases out of the way so you don't have to keep any more context in mind while reading the main case.

Comment: It's also performance! More than half the nodes in a tree are leaves. Suppose we traverse the one-cell tree `(1 . 2)`.  We encounter 2 cases that are "Leaf", and only 1 case that is "Pair".  You want to test the more frequent cases first. Compilers can typically only figure out that sort of thing under special optimizations that rely on profiling data.

Comment: Note that in a classical Lisp, we wouldn't need this ugly `(not (pair? x))` construction, because everything that is not a `cons` is an `atom`, and that word is the name of a predicate function:  `(cond ((null x) ...) ((atom x) ...) (t ...))`.